# creating syntax of regularexpression for multiple email address in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, syntax, validation

I want to create a regular expression for a RegularExpressionValidator in Asp.net...

I want to create the following expression

(emailaddress ([,][SPACE]* emailaddress)* )?

emailaddress = \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*

please check if emailaddress is correct, and how can I create the syntax for the above expression
thank you

Comment: Here's a page with a regular expression email address validator: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html - email addresses are more complicated that you thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address),

```
ValidationExpression="(?:(?:^|,\s*)[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})\s*)+"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
ValidationExpression="^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+"

                        + @"(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+)*)|(\"".+\""))@"

                        + @"((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"

                        + @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+"

                        + @"[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"
```

You can use this site in order to create your regex : RegexHero